# jQuery functions in an overlay

Tags: jquery, overlay

I have an overlay in which i have placed one .jsp file which has one textbox.
Find below the content of .jsp file:

```
<input id="sample" size="15" type="text">
```

Now i want to fire a keyup event on this textbox using below jQuery function:

```
jQuery(function() {
  alert("hi 1");
  //will perform some other tasks//
  jQuery("sample").keyup(function() {
    alert("hi 2");                  
  });
});
```

Note:
Nothing is coming up.

Comment: Please format your code using the 10101 icon in the editor

Answer (score 1):

You need a `#` in an [`#id` selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) (otherwise it's an [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/), looking for a `<sample>` element), like this:

```
jQuery("#sample").keyup(function() {
  alert("hi 2");                    
});
```

Comment: @Sri - your original question didn't have it...that's the code I cleaned up, what your *actual* code...and are you wanting to attach an event handler, or fire the event?

Comment: in the original post the # is missing but i have used that.

Comment: @Sri - are you getting any errors in the console? The code you posted works as-is, you can test it here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/VScSp/ ...there's something *else* happening outside the posted code if you've updated to use `#`.  For example is that `id="sample"` used only once?

Comment: No error are coming up...and the id="sample" is used only once         Now my code looks like jQuery("#sample").keyup(function() {
  alert("hi 2");                    
});

Comment: @Sri - you're expecting this to alert when a keyup event happens on the input, right? not actually fire immediately?

Comment: yes i am expecting alert to happen once the key up event is fired

Comment: @Sri - If you have a link to a page I can take a look...otherwise I'm not sure what to tell you, what you posted works (you can see it in the demo link in my previous comment), your actual page differ somehow from what you posted...need to see what that difference is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're not calling jQuery right. The selectors in jQuery are similar to CSS - `#yourId` and `.yourClassName`

You'll need:

```
    jQuery("#sample").keyup(
        function() {
            alert("hi 2");                  
        }
    );
```

Comment: in the original post the # is missing but i have used that but of no use